# porting rcp application to java 8

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, java-8

I am a newbie in developing RCP application. I am trying to execute application which is built with plug-in in RCP. When I try to run the application it gives me following null pointer exception. I am not able to understand where my code is breaking or where to look to resolve this exception. Can someone please help? The application is not able to execute with java 1.7 or 1.8. Thank you in advance.

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 0 2014-12-19 16:29:26.893
!MESSAGE Unhandled event loop exception
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.actions.CommandAction.init(CommandAction.java:201)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.actions.CommandAction.<init>(CommandAction.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.actions.CommandAction.<init>(CommandAction.java:65)
    at org.eclipse.ui.actions.ActionFactory$WorkbenchCommandAction.<init>(ActionFactory.java:77)
    at org.eclipse.ui.actions.ActionFactory$64.create(ActionFactory.java:1750)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.presentations.util.StandardEditorSystemMenu.<init>(StandardEditorSystemMenu.java:44)
    at org.eclipse.ui.presentations.WorkbenchPresentationFactory.createEditorPresentation(WorkbenchPresentationFactory.java:78)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.presentations.PresentationFactoryUtil.createPresentation(PresentationFactoryUtil.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartStack.createControl(PartStack.java:567)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartSashContainer.createControl(PartSashContainer.java:568)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorSashContainer.createControl(EditorSashContainer.java:531)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorAreaHelper.<init>(EditorAreaHelper.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.init(WorkbenchPage.java:2507)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.<init>(WorkbenchPage.java:637)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.tweaklets.Workbench3xImplementation.createWorkbenchPage(Workbench3xImplementation.java:39)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.busyOpenPage(WorkbenchWindow.java:796)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$23.runWithException(Workbench.java:1224)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.StartupThreading$StartupRunnable.run(StartupThreading.java:31)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4140)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3757)
    at org.eclipse.ui.application.WorkbenchAdvisor.openWindows(WorkbenchAdvisor.java:803)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$33.runWithException(Workbench.java:1595)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.StartupThreading$StartupRunnable.run(StartupThreading.java:31)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4140)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3757)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2604)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2494)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:674)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:667)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at com.sequenom.typerdx.application.Application$1.run(Application.java:83)
    at com.sequenom.typerdx.application.Application$1.run(Application.java:1)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Unknown Source)
    at com.sequenom.typerdx.application.Application.login(Application.java:114)
    at com.sequenom.typerdx.application.Application.start(Application.java:204)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:622)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1410)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1386)
19 Dec 2014 16:29:27,096 [ERROR] com.packagename.ApplicationWorkbenchAdvisor: java.lang.NullPointerException
19 Dec 2014 16:29:27,127 [ERROR] com.packagename.ServicesActivator$2: Sleep thread interrupted. sleep interrupted
```

Comment: You're a what-now? ...Sorry, bad joke. Anyway, it looks like something is `null` when you call a method on it. Look at the furthest-down line in that stack trace that's in your code and find what's potentially null. Post the relevant section of code. It should help.

Comment: ok i will look into that..